# maximum matching number decreases when vertices collapse?

Tags: graphs, matching

It seems that the maximum matching number **decreases** when some *independent* (not connected) vertices collapse into one vertex, but I don't know if it is absolutely true. 
Would maximum matching number **increases** when two vertices are connected to form a new edge?

Any proof? Thanks!
 [image]
Definitions:
Given a graph G = (V,E), a **[matching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_(graph_theory))** M in G is a set of pairwise non-adjacent edges; that is, no two edges share a common vertex.

A **[maximum matching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_(graph_theory))** (also known as maximum-cardinality matching[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YRJw2.png)) is a matching that contains the largest possible number of edges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just find the proof in Karp, Richard M., and Michael Sipser. "Maximum matching in sparse random graphs." Foundations of Computer Science, 1981. SFCS'81. 22nd Annual Symposium on. IEEE, 1981.

Answer (score 2):

Try to find a proof that it can't happen! Keep trying.  Hint:

> Suppose you have a maximum matching for the collapsed graph.  Can you use that to find a matching for the original graph?  How many edges does it have?  What does that imply about your question?

If you're really stuck, try to write a program to enumerate all graphs with at most 6 vertices (say) and see if the matching number can ever increase after collapsing an edge.  That should enable you to form a reasonable conjecture, which you can then try to prove, or should give you a counterexample.